# How can I retrieve XML nodes dynamically from SQL Server and use XDocument to build a file from a template with them?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML template with all the headers I need. I load it with `XDocument`, and then build the nodes using `XElements`. However, this means I am currently hard coding the data bits I need to go into my file.

I noticed with SQL Server I can use the `XML` datatype to store data in the database. Using this approach it would be better to look through each record and dynamically build the `XML` file.

However, I see some issues with my approach. There may be two nodes that share the same parent. Is there a way to store the nodes and their parent, and use something in `XDocument` to merge them?

Here is a sample chunk of my XML

```
<AddInfoCollection>
    <AddInfo>
        <Key>TransportReference</Key>
        <Value>666777888</Value>
    </AddInfo>              
    <AddInfo>
        <Key>UI_NKCarrierSCAC</Key>
        <Value>ABCD</Value>
    </AddInfo>              
    <AddInfo>
        <Key>SchDLoading</Key>
        <Value>1234</Value>
    </AddInfo>  
    <AddInfo>
        <Key>SchDArrival</Key>
        <Value>12345</Value>
    </AddInfo>                  
</AddInfoCollection>
```

In the database, I'd imagine the table would be:

- `Field (varchar(200)`
- `Value (varchar(200)`
- `XML`

Sample:

```
Field                 Value          XML
----------------------------------------------------------------
TransportReference    666777888      <AddInfoCollection>
                                       <AddInfo>
                                         <Key>TransportReference</Key>
                                         <Value>666777888</Value>
                                       </AddInfo>   
                                     <AddInfoCollection>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SELECT... FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx).

For example:

```
USE ADVENTUREWORKS
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM HUMANRESOURCES.EMPLOYEE FOR XML PATH
```

This returns the resultset as the following XML. Use other variants of SELECT...FOR XML to tailor the XML to your requirements.

```
<row>
  <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
  <NationalIDNumber>14417807</NationalIDNumber>
  <ContactID>1209</ContactID>
  <LoginID>adventure-works\guy1</LoginID>
  <ManagerID>16</ManagerID>
  <Title>Production Technician - WC60</Title>
  <BirthDate>1972-05-15T00:00:00</BirthDate>
  <MaritalStatus>M</MaritalStatus>
  <Gender>M</Gender>
  <HireDate>1996-07-31T00:00:00</HireDate>
  <SalariedFlag>0</SalariedFlag>
  <VacationHours>21</VacationHours>
  <SickLeaveHours>30</SickLeaveHours>
  <CurrentFlag>1</CurrentFlag>
  <rowguid>AAE1D04A-C237-4974-B4D5-935247737718</rowguid>
  <ModifiedDate>2004-07-31T00:00:00</ModifiedDate>
</row>
<row>
  <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
  <NationalIDNumber>253022876</NationalIDNumber>
  <ContactID>1030</ContactID>
  <LoginID>adventure-works\kevin0</LoginID>
  <ManagerID>6</ManagerID>
  <Title>Marketing Assistant</Title>
  <BirthDate>1977-06-03T00:00:00</BirthDate>
  <MaritalStatus>S</MaritalStatus>
  <Gender>M</Gender>
  <HireDate>1997-02-26T00:00:00</HireDate>
  <SalariedFlag>0</SalariedFlag>
  <VacationHours>42</VacationHours>
  <SickLeaveHours>41</SickLeaveHours>
  <CurrentFlag>1</CurrentFlag>
  <rowguid>1B480240-95C0-410F-A717-EB29943C8886</rowguid>
  <ModifiedDate>2004-07-31T00:00:00</ModifiedDate>
</row>
```

Comment: Unfortunately due to the design of the table and data this wont work. Basically <AddInfoCollection> is not the only thing we will get back from the DB. There may be all kinds of other types with an untold number of nested elements. At this point is looking more practical to hardcode the fields since there might not be a way to make my DB generic enough to accommodate any XML that needs to meet my template.